# Better, more accurate mime type detection in Python

Tags: python, mime-types, python-2.7

Python's mimetypes module isn't especially accurate and bases its results on the file extension. The only way I can think of to get a more accurate result is to call the Unix `file` command with `subprocess.Popen` as so:

```
import subprocess
mimetype = subprocess.Popen(['file', '/path/to/file', '--mime-type', '-b'], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().strip()
```

This feels inelegant. Is there a better way to do this *without* having to call `file` but still achieving the same level of accuracy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try out : [magic's mimetype](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

Comment: True - but it is more elegant, which is what he asked for. :)

Answer (score 2):

I use something similar but slightly abbreviated:

```
import subprocess
mimeType = subprocess.check_output(['file', '-ib', '/path/to/file']).strip()
```

It may not be more elegant, but it's shorter and a bit easier to read, and I always prefer that.